# How to access Google Storage bucket from an external PHP application

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket on Google Storage with public files, and I have a PHP web application running on another hosting (not App Engine). I wasn't able to figure out how to access those files from my application - the Documentation only covers access by app engine's apps. Does someone has managed to access a Storage bucket from a PHP app outside Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Search Google "Google Storage PHP".  One of the top results leads you here: https://cloud.google.com/php/samples/storage

Comment: My problem is expressed on that same page: "This document describes how to use the Google Cloud Client Library to store and retrieve data using Cloud Storage **in an App Engine app**."

Answer (score 1):

The programmatic access is done just about the same when using [Google Cloud PHP](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php), but you'll need to do a bit more work to authenticate when running on a non-app engine/compute engine server. The best way is to use a Service Account. Google Cloud PHP has some [documentation on how to get started with a Service Account](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.32.1/guides/authentication).

Once you have your service account keyfile (it's a .json file), just create your client, providing it with the keyfile location.

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/keyfile.json'
]);
```

Once you've done this, you will be authenticated and able to make calls just as you could on app engine.

Comment: Thanks bro! I'll give it a try.